# Blue Card and Bachelor of Fine Arts in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, blue-card

I have a Bachelor of Fine Arts in Graphics Design (4 year degree) of a H+ certified school that I found in Anabin http://anabin.kmk.org/anabin.html and would like to apply for a Blue Card in Germany.

I can't find my degree in the database (or any Fine Arts for that matter) so I'm thinking of going through the process of obtaining https://www.kmk.org/kmk/information-in-english/statement-of-comparability-for-foreign-higher-education-qualifications.html

Has anyone here done this and has experiences to share? Is this even possible with a Bachelor of Fine Arts?

My official job title will be Software Developer while I'm there, since I transition from a Design heavy role to more Developer oriented one.

Comment: This is specifically about the application process for certifiyng the degree with KMK. The question is basically does this count as a degree that will be regocnized as a College degree. I'm fairly certain for a blue card it is not necceary to have an actual STEM degree.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here was `no`. As long as your job title is "Software Developer" the actual degree didn't seem to matter (for reference: this was in Germany)